# zoom canvas with clipto not working

Tags: javascript, fabricjs, zooming

Using *fabric.js*, when i use `setZoom()`, `clipTo()` is not responding and staying at the same width & height. Code works for objects inside canvas. I've already tested with zoomToPoint but didn't solve my problem.

```
function zoomIn() {
zoomLevel += .2;

canvas.setZoom(zoomLevel);
canvas.setDimensions({
    width: my_canvas_width * zoomLevel,
    height: my_canvas_height * zoomLevel
});
}
```

`clipTo()` code that i'm using:

```
canvas.clipTo = function(ctx) {
 ctx.rect(0,0,300,300);
}
```

Any ideas why `clipTo` is not responding to `setZoom()`? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is important that you specify that you are using *fabric.js*. I'm not sure that I understand your problem correctly, the reason `clipTo` stays the same is because of the lines

```
canvas.setDimensions({
    width: my_canvas_width * zoomLevel,
    height: my_canvas_height * zoomLevel
});
```

Setting image dimensions is pretty much clipping the image, `clipTo()` won't work **after** you set the dimensions.

I think you don't need those lines, see this [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/v1tmsmqj/1/), there a 500x500 image is always clipped to 300x300.